# select query returns wrong result in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

When I select a field using oracle select below issue occurs

In Emp table I have unique employee details with unique empid.

```
select name,dob,empid from emp where empid=100;
```

The above query returns the correct name,dob,empid of the employee.

```
NAME       DOB        EMPID
-----      ---------  -----
Praba      02-Nov-87    100


select name,dob,empid from emp where empid=100 and name is null;
```

now the name is return as null and dob , empid like below

```
NAME   DOB         EMPID
----   ---------   -----
Null   02-Nov-87   100
```

I am sure the table has only one entry for empid 100. please help me to resolve

Comment: Please format your code to make the question readable. (I just did it for you but then you made a change that overwrote mine!)

Comment: thank you tony but i can't able to draw table
 i just tried that

Comment: in the first select i am getting correct result but when i add is null in the query the name is replace by null value in result.

Comment: I find this improbable.  Are you certain both queries are being executed against the same data set (you don't have a prod and test environment here with different results do you?) You don't have uncommitted data in a session which oracle is using in one case and not in the other?

Comment: yes both queries are being executed against the same data set in production.
but we used dump keyword in the where condition resolves the problem. but can't able to find out the cause.